# pom.xml gives exception while converting a dynamic web project to maven project

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, spring, maven

I am using eclipse kepler version.When i tried to convert a dynamic web project to maven,

pom.xml showed the following exception:

```
Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven-war-plugin:2.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved.Failed to read artifact description for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:jar:2.3
```

Can anyone please tell me what should i do about it. I went through similar type of question asked by other users, there it was told to change something in `settings.xml` file in repository folder.But when i went to `.m2/repository` folder, i could not find any `settings.xml` file. Seems to me there is no settings.xml file there.

Comment: Did you try reimporting the project ? I have had this issue and I had to re import the project and it started working . Also try running mvn from commandline to see if it works

Comment: show pom.xml, and do maven force update

Comment: How to do that.I mean how can i force update.And @Rocky i just found the import option but i don't know how to reimport the project.I have not found the reimport option.How do i reimport.

Comment: i have updated the project by going to maven and update project.But that does not work.

Comment: Delete the project from workspace (but do not delete it from the filesystem) , after that create a new maven project and in the options select checkout existing maven project and when it asks for the root directory , point it to the pom.xml on your filesystem. This would reimport the poject into eclipse

Comment: Thanks a lot, its working for me now.Actually, before i was unable to find the maven force update option.Now, i found it.I clicked on the maven>force update of snapshots and releases and it worked for me now.